# Mapbox > Geofencing with Turf.js on rendered elements?

Tags: javascript, nodes, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, turfjs

I am trying to use Mapbox/Turfjs to understand how many points are in a polygon. I have rendered my polygon and points in map.onload Is then possible to call Turf.js from another function AFTER the polygon and points have been rendered to the map?

Something like this...?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'eeeeeeeeee';

    map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
        center: [ 32.62939453125,1.7355743631421197], 
        zoom: 6.5,
        pitch: 40,          
        maxZoom: 17
    });


    map.on('load', function () {

        //geofence data
        map.addSource('fencedata', {
            type: 'geojson',
            data: 'data/fence.geojson'
        });

        map.addLayer({
            id: 'fence',
            type: 'fill',
            "source": "fencedata",
            'layout': {},
            'paint': {
                'fill-color': '#FF0000',
                'fill-opacity': 0.3
            }
        });


        //points data
        map.addSource("pointdata", {
            type: "geojson",
            data: 'data/points.geojson',
            cluster: true,
            clusterRadius: 20 
        });

        map.addLayer({
            "id": "points",
            "type": "circle",
            "source": "pointdata",
            "paint": {
                'circle-color': 'rgba(255, 255, 46, 1.0)',
                'circle-radius': 8
            }
        });


    });

    map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());



});


geofence();    


function geofence(){

    var ptsWithin = turf.within(points, fence);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your points as GeoJSON, and your polygon as GeoJSON - so, yes, you can use TurfJS to find out which points are within the polygon. It looks like the code you've proposed is correct. The fact you're using Mapbox is irrelevant to this particular task.

If you're experiencing a problem with this approach, indicate it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `geofence()` function inside the map on-load function after adding those layers, By that way you can make sure that the `geofence()` function is called after the layers have been loaded

```
    map.on('load', function () {

    //geofence data
    map.addSource('fencedata', {
        type: 'geojson',
        data: 'data/fence.geojson'
    });

    map.addLayer({
        id: 'fence',
        type: 'fill',
        "source": "fencedata",
        'layout': {},
        'paint': {
            'fill-color': '#FF0000',
            'fill-opacity': 0.3
        }
    });


    //points data
    map.addSource("pointdata", {
        type: "geojson",
        data: 'data/points.geojson',
        cluster: true,
        clusterRadius: 20
    });

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "points",
        "type": "circle",
        "source": "pointdata",
        "paint": {
            'circle-color': 'rgba(255, 255, 46, 1.0)',
            'circle-radius': 8
        }
    });
    geofence();
  });
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
});

function geofence() {
   var ptsWithin = turf.within(points, fence);
}
```